# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null- while using -http://localhost:8080/

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

When I tried running the below code (IndecisionApp.js) with live-server with http://127.0.0.1:8080/, the code very well displayed the output. But the I installed webpack version of 3.1.0, webpack-cli of version 3.3.12, and webpack-dev-server of version 2.5.1. But when the webpack-dev-server was run on http://localhost:8080/, using yarn run webpack-dev-server, it showed the error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null at ...

Basically, the optionsArray array was being referred to as null at the time of loading. Issue is found for the handleOptions property of Action tag in render. One of the answers I saw suggested to use the try-catch method, but the error persisted. Please help me in solving this error, since nothing is getting displayed on the screen

[error console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfaVI.png)

Code:

```
import React from 'react';
...
import Action from "./Action";

export default class IndecisionApp extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        optionsArray: []
    }

    this.handleDeleteOptions = this.handleDeleteOptions.bind(this)
    this.handlePick = this.handlePick.bind(this);
    this.handleAddOptions = this.handleAddOptions.bind(this);
    this.handleDeleteSingleOption = this.handleDeleteSingleOption.bind(this);
    
}

componentDidMount(){
    try {
        const json = localStorage.getItem('options');
        const options = JSON.parse(json);

        this.setState(() => ({ optionsArray: options }));
    }
    catch(e) {
        // Do nothing
    }
    
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState){                   
    // Saving Data to local storage
    if(prevState.optionsArray.length !== this.state.optionsArray.length){
        const json = JSON.stringify(this.state.optionsArray);
        localStorage.setItem('options', json);
    }
}

handleDeleteOptions(){
    this.setState(() => ({ optionsArray: [] }));
}

handleDeleteSingleOption(optionToRemove){
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        optionsArray: prevState.optionsArray.filter((option) => {
            return (optionToRemove !== option)                      // Returns true or false, since filter method is being used
        })
    }));
}

handlePick(){
    const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.state.optionsArray.length);
    const option = this.state.optionsArray[randomNum];
    alert(option);
}

handleAddOptions(option){
    // Validation of string input for adding item
    if(!option){
        return 'Enter valid value to add item'
    }
    else if(this.state.optionsArray.indexOf(option) > -1){
        return 'This option already exsits'
    }

    this.setState((prevState) => ({ optionsArray: prevState.optionsArray.concat(option) }));
}

render(){
    const subtitle = 'Assisting you to take your decisions';

    return(
        <div>
            <Header subtitle={subtitle} />

            <Action 
                hasOptions={this.state.optionsArray.length > 0} 
                handlePick={this.handlePick}
            />

            <Options 
                options={this.state.optionsArray} 
                handleDeleteOptions={this.handleDeleteOptions} 
                handleDeleteSingleOption={this.handleDeleteSingleOption}
            />

            <AddOption  
                options={this.state.optionsArray} 
                handleAddOptions={this.handleAddOptions}
            />  
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

Comment: I think you may have a bootstrapping issue when mounting the component and fetching "options" from localStorage if localStorage hasn't been set yet. Can you verify `const json = localStorage.getItem('options');` that `json` is not undefined/null?

Comment: try this    hasOptions={this.state.optionsArray && this.state.optionsArray.length > 0} i your render method

Comment: @vaibhavmaster Thanks for it. After using this, this error got cleared, but I encountered similar errors. But this approach helped me in solving those bugs too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial state is a defined, empty array, so the guard *shouldn't* be necessary as a length check on an empty array, (`[].length`) is perfectly valid and sufficient.

```js
console.log([].length);
```

As I asked in my comment, it appears *something* is mutating your state or otherwise updating it to something ***other*** than an empty array. If when fetching `localStorage.getItem('options')` and there is no stored "options" key-value, then `null` is returned. You then JSON parse this, which also returns null, then you update your state with a null value.

```
const json = localStorage.getItem('options'); // possibly null
const options = JSON.parse(json); // returns null if json === null

this.setState(() => ({ optionsArray: options })); // just possibly stored null
```

This won't work here in SO, but try this in your own console

```
const json = localStorage.getItem('dEfInItElYpRoBaBlYnOtAkEy'); // null
JSON.parse(json); // null
```

You should instead check the result of fetching from localStorage

```
const json = localStorage.getItem('options');
if (json) {
  // truthy and exists (i.e. not null or undefined)
  try {
    const options = JSON.parse(json);
    this.setState(() => ({ optionsArray: options }));
  } catch(err) {
    // handle error, likely from bad JSON parsing
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the approach given above helps in resolving the error.

Basically, we must observe that the optionsArray is declared/initialized as an empty array. So, when we try to find its length, it is shown to be null, which does not allow the program to display anything, throwing an error. So, to overcome this problem, we can use the Conditional JSX method, specifically the logical AND operator(&&).

```
{this.state.optionsArray && this.state.optionsArray.length > 0}
```

In this, we write 2 statements to compare. If the first statement is true (here 'this.state.optionsArray'), it will execute the second statement and hence we will be able to overcome the issue of encountering null.

A similar approach must be followed while debugging the code later since we are using an empty array. This method of using the logical AND operator is very helpful in encountering errors, especially in such cases.

This is my first answer on StackOverflow, so please do help in improving the answer, if required.